# How do I use pytest and unittest.mock to mock interactions with a paramiko.SSHClient

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest.mock, pytest-mock

I am trying to write a unit test for code that interacts with an SFTP server using the `paramiko` library. The code under test receives a list of remote file locations and a callback. Each file is fetched and sent into the callback. The test shall simulate a scenario, where the caller sends two files to visit and one of the files fails with an IOError. I want to make sure that the failing file is excluded from the response.

Here is the `code.py`:

```
import io
from typing import Callable, List
import typing
import paramiko


def visit_files(files: List[str], callback: Callable[[typing.BinaryIO], None]) -> List[str]:
    response = []
    with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())        
        ssh.connect("test.rebex.net", port=22, username="demo", password="password")

        with ssh.open_sftp() as sftp:
            for file_name in files:
                try:
                    with sftp.open(file_name, "rb") as f:
                        try:
                            b = f.read()
                            callback(io.BytesIO(b))
                            response.append(file_name)
                        except ValueError:
                            print("Something went wrong")
                except IOError:
                    print("Unknown IO error")
    return response
```

And my `test_code.py`:

```
import typing
from unittest.mock import Mock
from pytest_mock import MockerFixture

from src.utils.code import visit_files

def test_visiting(mocker: MockerFixture):
        mock = mocker.patch('paramiko.SSHClient')

        ssh_client_mock = mock.return_value
        ssh_client_mock.connect.return_value = Mock()

        sftp_mock = ssh_client_mock.open_sftp.return_value
        sftp_mock.open.side_effect = [
            Mock(read=Mock(return_value=b'Hello, World!')),  # Mock for the first file
            IOError("Unable to open file"),  # Simulate IOError for the second file
        ]

        def print_size(b: typing.BinaryIO) -> None:
                print(b.tell())

        response = visit_files(files=["file1.txt", "file2.txt"], callback=print_size)
        assert response == ["file1.txt"]
```

The error I am receiving is: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'MagicMock'` in line `callback(io.BytesIO(b))`. I can't figure out where my mocks are not set up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this, starting by refactoring `visit_files` so you can inject the client dependency

```
import io
from typing import Callable, List
import typing
import paramiko


def visit_files(files: List[str], callback: Callable[[typing.BinaryIO], None], client: paramiko.SSHClient = None) -> List[str]:
    response = []
    if not client:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient
    with client() as ssh:
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())        
        ssh.connect("test.rebex.net", port=22, username="demo", password="password")

        with ssh.open_sftp() as sftp:
            for file_name in files:
                try:
                    with sftp.open(file_name, "rb") as f:
                        try:
                            b = f.read()
                            callback(io.BytesIO(b))
                            response.append(file_name)
                        except ValueError:
                            print("Something went wrong")
                except IOError:
                    print("Unknown IO error")
    return response
```

and then, create `SSHClientMock` taking into account the context managers:

```
import typing
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
import paramiko
from contextlib import contextmanager
import io

from src.utils.code import visit_files


class SSHClientMock(MagicMock):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(spec=paramiko.SSHClient, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self):
        pass

    @contextmanager
    def open_sftp(self):
        def _open_sftp_mock_open(filename, mode):
            if filename == "file1.txt":
                return io.BytesIO(b"Hello World!")
            elif filename == "file2.txt":
                raise IOError("Unable to open file")
            assert False

        open_sftp_mock = MagicMock()
        open_sftp_mock.open = _open_sftp_mock_open
        yield open_sftp_mock


def test_visiting():
        def print_size(b: typing.BinaryIO) -> None:
                print(b.tell())

        response = visit_files(files=["file1.txt", "file2.txt"], callback=print_size, client=SSHClientMock())
        assert response == ["file1.txt"]
```